# Object pinned to github repo is experiencing delays when called back using pin_get

Tags: r, github, pins

When I call back a pinned object from github I noticed that it does not return the latest updated version and there is at least five minutes delay. Here is an example:

```
board_register_github(name = "GitHub-BFDD", repo = "AkthemRehab/BFDD", branch = "main")
Results <- data.frame(Results=numeric(), stringsAsFactors = F)
pin(Results, "Results", board = "GitHub-BFDD")
```

Now lets add one record to the Results data frame and update the pin:

```
Results[nrow(Results)+1,] <- as.numeric(10)
pin(Results, "Results", board = "GitHub-BFDD")
```

When I recall the updated Results data frame it take at least 5-10 minutes before reflecting the update. When I check the csv file in github it get updated instantaneously though. I use this command to get the updated pin to my R environment:

```
Results <- pin_get("Results", board = "GitHub-BFDD")
```

I am updating the Results data frame quiet often in my application and would like pins to reflect the updates in real-time.

Edit: Any updates or inputs to that question ?

Comment: Your values are probably being cached so they aren't constantly being re-downloaded. Try `Results <- pin_get("Results", board = "GitHub-BFDD", cache=FALSE)`. See `?cache_info` for more info

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git. You're merely using some Git repository. You're also using your internet connection, but you didn't tag this with [tag:tcp-ip] for instance; please don't use the Git tag if you're not running Git commands. (I suspect the [tag:github] tag is inappropriate here as well, unless your question comes down to particular GitHub APIs.)

Comment: @MrFlick I tried to add cache=FALSE but there is still a delay when I call the object with pin_get.

Comment: @torek Noted. However, there is a small chance the delay has something to do with where the file is hosted (i.e. git and/or github), especially that, when I update a file and check it in github, I find the update reflected instantly in but the pin_get command doesnot return the latest file except after a delay of 5-10 minutes.